# Can I pass a class reference as a parameter to a function in VBNet?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Please forgive me if I use improper terminology or sound like a complete noob.

When calling a sub in a class library, I'd like to pass not an instantiated form, but just a reference to the class that represents the form. Then I want to instantiate the form from within the class library function. Is this possible?

Something like the following:

**In the main application:**

```
ClassLib.MyClass.DisplayForm(GetType(Form1))
```

**Then, in the class library:**

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public Shared Sub DisplayForm(WhichFormClass As Type)
        Dim MyForm as Form = WhichFormClass.CreateObject() 'Getting imaginitive
        MyForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hopefully my example conveys what I'm trying to accomplish. If you think my approach is bogus, I'm open to alternative strategies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additionally to MotoSV's answer, here is a version that uses only generics:

```
Public Shared Sub DisplayForm(Of T As {New, Form})()
    Dim instance = New T()
    instance.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Which you can use like:

```
DisplayForm(Of Form1)()
```

With this approach you can be sure that the passed type is a form and that the instance has the `ShowDialog()` method. There is no cast necessary that might fail eventually. However, it is necessary to know the type parameter at design time in order to call the method.

Comment: Awesome. I love the elegance of this approach for the advantages that you mention.

Comment: Nico, if I wanted to pass a parameter to the constructor on Form1, what would I need to change? I'd want to do something like:
Dim instance = New T(IdNum)

Comment: That is not directly possible. Either you have to use reflection to get the constructor and invoke it (similar to MotoSV's answer). Or you can create an interface with the necessary properties. And after creating the instance with the default constructor set the properties.

Comment: So then, using your original approach, I'm guessing only way to send parameters to the new form instance would be to create the form object, assign a value to the form's Tag property, then perhaps process that value in the form's Activate event? This seems a bit kludgy but maybe it could work.

Comment: Nico, I too really like the elegance of this solution, exactly what I was looking for in my case. The fact that you can specify that the generic must be of type Form leads me to believe this would be very useful for other base types, but could you elaborate on the usage of the curly braces in the generic type clause (forgive my terminology if its a bit off), I've never seen that usage before, only (Of T).

Comment: @BMB The `As` clause in the generic type parameter declaration denotes a constraint of the parameter. In this case there are two constraints; that's why the curly braces are necessary. `As New` specifies that the type must have a default parameterless constructor. `As Form` specifies that the parameter must be a subclass of `Form`.

Comment: Don't try it if you have a little hierarchy of shared/static methods as these don't evaluate. Yes, I've 5 classes that are small and use generics and inheritance but there was no case for instances. Except maybe this :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Dim classType As Type = GetType(Form1)
```

Then call the method:

```
DisplayForm(classType)
```

You can then use this type information and reflection to create an instance at runtime in the DisplayForm method:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(classType)
```

Note that this is a simple example and performs no error checking, etc. You should read a bit more on reflection to make sure you handle any potential problems.

Edit 1:

Simple example:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public Shared Sub DisplayForm(ByVal formType As Type)
        Dim form As Form = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(formType), Form)
        form.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

You use the method as:

```
Dim formType As Type = GetType(Form1)
MyClass.DisplayForm(formType)
```

Again, best to perform some error checking in all of this.

Comment: +1, but be sure to cast the created instance to `Form` instead of `Form1`. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to pass the class to the method.

Comment: This approach looks nice... Maybe not as airtight as Nico's but possibly more flexible or adaptable to other uses. I'll definitely keep this one in my toolbelt.

Comment: @MotoSV - Same follow-up I asked Nico: How could I adapt this approach so that I can provide a parameter to the custom form's constructor? As in: Dim form As New MyForm(value)